# Spring boot rest api - Can I get response without creating any java class(DTO's or entity) for the response object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm implementing spring boot rest api application, in which I invoke stored procedure (which returns back refcursor). I need to show that response as JSON object with key, value pair without creating any DTO's or entity for that response. Is it possible to achieve the above requirement?

I get response(Cursor) from stored procedure.

**@Override**

public List getOrder(String orderNo) {
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("xx.xxx.get_order_details"); query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN); query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR); 
query.setParameter(1, "OR-1001");
List results = query.getResultList();.

Comment: Could anyone knows on how to convert procedure response(may receive multiple cursor's as a response) to Map or to JSONNode ????

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can either return `Map<String, Object>` from your controller class or use the generic `JsonNode` class from Jackson.

An example of the Map might be the following (with the help of Java 11):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public")
public class PublicController {

  @GetMapping("/data")
  public Map<String, Object> returnFoo() {
    Map<String, Object> resultFromDatabase = Map.of("name", "duke", "data",
      Map.of("id", 1337, "enabled", true));
    return resultFromDatabase;
  }
}
```

The result is the following

```
curl -v localhost:8080/public/data

{"data":{"id":1337,"enabled":true},"name":"duke"}
```

It is also possible to just return `Object`, but then you have to make sure the result of your database is always parsable to JSON, as you otherwise might get exceptions:

```
@GetMapping("/data")
public Object returnFoo() {
  Map<String, Object> resultFromDatabase = Map.of("name", "duke", "data",
    Map.of("id", 1337, "enabled", true));
  return resultFromDatabase;
}
```

Comment: please add this code properly formatted to your question

Comment: Thanks @rieckpil. Added code snippet in my question.  Is there any way to convert resultSet to map or resultset to JSONNode?